# Error installing PyPI package with pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm having serious issues trying to use pip to install a PyPI package. I'm totally new to Python and not particularly knowledgeable about computers in general. So if anyone knows how to fix this, please explain it to me in plain English.

When I try to run pip in cmd I get the following message..

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Pythhon\python.exe"   "C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe"  '
```

Notice the spaces between between the double quotes. 
I previously changed the the folder name of my Python directory (it was misspelled) which I suspect has something to do with this. After a lot of searching and tinkering with `PATH` from environment variables I just can't seem to get pip to work.

I'm running `python3.4` and in my Scripts folder I have several files (`pip`, `pip3.4`, `pip3`, `easy_install`, `easy_install-3.4`) and I don't know what any of it means.

My ultimate goal is to install the package `yahoo-finance`.

Comment: So did you fix your PATH? It seems one executable thinks it is in `C:\Pythhon` and the other is in `C:\Python`

Comment: Yes I did fix the PATH. When I run PATH in cmd the last entry is 'C:\Python\Scripts' so I'm assuming it's correct

Comment: You should have an entry for just 'C:\Python\' as well as 'C:\Python\Scripts'

Comment: Ok. But this still does not solve my issue. I'm wondering how to remove the first incorrect directory reference "Pythhon"

Comment: I understand the problem, I'm just trying to guess what is wrong. As you've said, you renamed the folder from "Pythhon" to "Python", then updated your PATH variables accordingly. The only other place I would think to look is in the registry, but I would typically avoid that at all cost and just uninstall and reinstall Python with the correctly spelled filepath.